# "Wake up an hour earlier each morning"

Tags: meaning, word-usage

I stumbled upon this sentence: "Wake up an hour earlier each morning".

This was listed as a good habit people should pick up. Given the context, I assume that it recommends you wake up an hour earlier than you usually (i.e. currently) would.

But could it also mean that you should wake up an hour earlier each morning going forward (compared to the previous one)? If not, what is a way to phrase it?

Answer (score 1):

The following answer is drawn from comments provided at the time of the question being posted:

[@McCaverty](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/197244) offers [this advice](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/366440/wake-up-an-hour-earlier-each-morning#comment855024_366440):

> "Unless it's an article called *Counter-clockwise: The Astonishing
>   Benefits of Sleep Deprivation*, I think most people would assume it
>   means just one hour earlier than normal going forward."

[@FumbleFingers](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/2637) provides [further insight](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/366440/wake-up-an-hour-earlier-each-morning#comment855032_366440):

> "For many years I really did used to go to bed half an hour *later*
>   every night - until eventually I'd find myself heading up the wooden
>   hill by dawn's early light (at which point I'd revert to a more
>   sensible bedtime, which would start slipping back again within days).
>   But as @McCaverty says, that would be a perverse interpretation for
>   OP's cited context."